# How to find and edit value of a template variable in expressionengine

Tags: templates, expressionengine

I am very new to expressionengine and need to make a change edit to a template variable. It is basically a variable named `{step_1_text}` and I just need to change the message it prints. For the life of me I cannot find out where or how this variable or expression or whatever it is called is defined.

Does anyone have any pointers where to look/what to try?

Appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are referring to is the content of a custom channel field tag, then you can edit the content of that within the channel entry: **Content -> Edit**

If it's a global variable you are referring to, then you can edit the content of that under **Design -> Templates -> Global Variables.** It could be a snippet, another type of variable, and for that you can edit the content at **Design -> Templates -> Snippets.**

It should be in one of those three places. Channel Tags, Global Variables and Snippets all have the {} brackets, so look the same on templates, although channel fields only would be inside of a Channel Tag pair.